# Understanding flow of control for Open-Source Projects and why so many classes?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, class

I'm working with Android Studio.
I have a problem, I tend to put all my functions in the MainClass and I know that's a bad practice (It's a little unclear so it would be very helpful if you could include what are the downsides to this).

I started reading a lot of open source code to improve this practice but it's very difficult for me to understand the flow of control since there's this insane amount of different classes and a lot of the code and functions seem alien when reading it for the first time. So how do I proceed with Understanding the flow?

Also I have a real problem splitting up my code into classes since it's passed by value in Java and so you have to return it to the variables for the next step; So can't I just create a function in the same class instead of another class , how would that affect the performance of my app?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why not to code in one class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113374/why-not-to-code-in-one-class)

Comment: Yes it helped a lot but i also want to know if it affects the performance of the application if every function is in one class?

Comment: Yes, it will affect the performance. If you have one huge "Main" file, then the entire class will have to be loaded. If this file is large you could potentially cause slowdowns in application start.

Comment: Just what i wanted to know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How your code is organized is highly dependent on what you are trying to accomplish. You may find it easier to understand large, opensource projects by learning about common design patterns first. Design patterns are common techniques or approaches to organizing code that solve a specific problem. For example, if you are designing a UI you would probably use the Model-View-Controller design pattern, where as if you were designing a game you might use an Entity-Component-System design pattern. There are hundreds of different design patterns that are used all over the place.

Comment: MVC is really a specific type of design pattern: an architectural one. You could not make the same claim about the builder pattern, for example. You wouldn't say "if you are designing a game you would probably use the builder pattern".